# How can I say "caps" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I am thinking of something like "screen caps" term in English. I mean the movie part with a subtitle, as a photo. How can I say "screen caps" / "movie caps" in Chinese?

Answer (score 4):

Generic screen caps in Chinese is `截圖 / 截图`. If you *really* want to specify it is from a movie, you can add "movies" in front, i.e. `電影截圖`, or for videos in general `影片截圖` or `視訊截圖`. Usually that is not very necessary.

Comment: @Alenanno Very classy, deleting comments for pointing out you made a mistake.